# TFS Team Project Portal permissions

Tags: tfs

I have added users to Contributor Group in Team Project, but they are not able access the Team Project Portal. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to manage permissions to TFS, Sharepoint and Reporting Services separately. This means that adding people to TFS groups does not automatically add them to Sharepoint and reporting services groups.

Please check below MSDN library for information on how to add users to Share Point Portal:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb558971.aspx

You can also use [TFS Administration tool](http://tfsadmin.codeplex.com/), which provides the options to add users to TFS, Sharepoint and Reporting Services from single place.

Comment: Ohh...I read it sometime back, but somehow forgot about this.Tnx!!